# Controls created with XamlReader.Parse don't inherit styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, xamlreader

In my application the user can type in HTML, which then gets converted to XAML. I then parse the XAML using the `XamlReader.Parse` method and add it to a `FlowDocument`.

For example, let's suppose I have the XAML for a paragraph stored in a string, and then I parse it and add it to a `FlowDocument` like so:

```
var xaml = @"<Paragraph Style=""{DynamicResource Big}"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">My paragraph</Paragraph>";
var paragraph = (Paragraph)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
MyDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Notice that the paragraph has a Style specified. That Style is defined in the `FlowDocument`'s Resources.

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument x:Name="MyDocument">
        <FlowDocument.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Red" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Paragraph}}"
                   x:Key="Big">
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="24" />
            </Style>
        </FlowDocument.Resources>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

You can see that I've defined two styles. The first is an implicit style, and the second extends the first using the `BasedOn` attribute. When I dynamically add the `Paragraph` to the `FlowDocument` it does pick up the 'Big' Style. However, there's a caveat, it does not pick up the Red Foreground color of the implicit style. How can I make it pick up both?

This only seems to be a problem when I parse the XAML. If I just instantiate a new `Paragraph` object and add it to the `FlowDocument`, it does indeed pick up both styles.